# How to Pick only Distinct Items from NSMutableArray (remove all doubles) With Minimal Code

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I tried to change them into an NSSet and then make a mutable copy.

```
keyIds = [[[NSSet setWithArray:keyIds] array]mutableCopy];
```

The result is this error:
2012-09-27 19:57:36.465 BadgerNew[81030:1303] -[__NSSetI array]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9f968b0

This is such a simple thing yet I do not know any direct way to do this.

Comment: yea allobjects. I found that out after asking this question.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Seems like a perfectly good question.

Comment: Maybe because it's too easy. The autocomplete offer me array so I thought it should be array. Turns out the correct method is allObjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is no method on an NSSet called array.

One way to convert an NSSet to an NSArray is to use the allObjects method:

```
keyIds = [[[NSSet setWithArray:keyIds] allObjects] mutableCopy]
```

However you will lose all ordering that you initially had with keyIds since a Set is inherently not ordered, so if that's the case, you might be better off storing keyIds as a set in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
NSSet *uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:myArrayWithLotsOfDuplicates];
NSArray *newArrayWithUniqueItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[uniqueItems allObjects]];
```

It won't have the order of your original, but each item will be unique...

Comment: Sorry Jason, didn't see your answer when I posted this